# Using functions and while loops together in PHP

Tags: php, function, date, while-loop

Ok, so I understand that a function can only be created once, but I need to use the output of a value from an array to run through the function 3 times on the same page. I've got it set up as i thought it should work, but php just produces a blank page. Here's the original function prior to me using it:

```
function time_ago($date,$granularity=2) {
    $date = strtotime($date);
    $difference = time() - $date;
    $periods = array('decade' => 315360000,
        'year' => 31536000,
        'month' => 2628000,
        'week' => 604800, 
        'day' => 86400,
        'hour' => 3600,
        'minute' => 60,
        'second' => 1);
    if ($difference < 5) { // less than 5 seconds ago, let's say "just now"
        $retval = "posted just now";
        return $retval;
    } else {                            
        foreach ($periods as $key => $value) {
            if ($difference >= $value) {
                $time = floor($difference/$value);
                $difference %= $value;
                $retval .= ($retval ? ' ' : '').$time.' ';
                $retval .= (($time > 1) ? $key.'s' : $key);
                $granularity--;
            }
            if ($granularity == '0') { break; }
        }
        return ' posted '.$retval.' ago';      
    }
}
```

then here's my basic loop, designed to pull tweets from a database and to convert the timestamp to unix time:

```
$sql = $db->select("SELECT * FROM `Twitter_tweets` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 0, 3");

while($res = $db->get_row($sql))
        {
            $p .= '
                <li>
                    <span class="tweetContent">'.display_clean($res['tweet']).'</span>
                    <br />
                    <span class="tweetDate">';

            $timeSince = ceil(abs(display_clean($res['created_at']) - time()) / 86400);

            $p .= ''.$timeSince.'</span>

                </li>
            ';
        }
```

The idea of the following section of code is to take the date in the database, convert to unixtime, find the difference between the two and then output it as 'posted x minutes ago', a la facebook/twitter etc:

```
//loop section converting date to 'posted x time ago'


$sql = $db->select("SELECT * FROM `Twitter_tweets` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 0, 3");

function time_ago($date,$granularity=2) {
    $date = strtotime($date);
    $difference = time() - $date;
    $periods = array('decade' => 315360000,
        'year' => 31536000,
        'month' => 2628000,
        'week' => 604800, 
        'day' => 86400,
        'hour' => 3600,
        'minute' => 60,
        'second' => 1);
}

    while($res = $db->get_row($sql))
        {
            $p .= '
                <li>
                    <span class="tweetContent">'.display_clean($res['tweet']).'</span>
                    <br />
                    <span class="tweetDate">';

            $date = display_clean($res['created_at']);

            if ($difference < 5) { // less than 5 seconds ago, let's say "just now"
                $retval = "posted just now";
                return $retval;
            } else {                            
                foreach ($periods as $key => $value) {
                    if ($difference >= $value) {
                        $time = floor($difference/$value);
                        $difference %= $value;
                        $retval .= ($retval ? ' ' : '').$time.' ';
                        $retval .= (($time > 1) ? $key.'s' : $key);
                        $granularity--;
                    }
                if ($granularity == '0') { break; }
                }
                return ' posted '.$retval.' ago';      
            }



            $p .= '</span>

                </li>
            ';
        }



//end loop
```

can anyone point out where i'm going wrong? I'm ok with using php, but i'm no expert by any means. I just can't see where i'm going wrong and causing a blank file to be output.

Comment: DateTime Interval is a whole lot easier to use than this mass of code

Comment: What datatype is created_at in your database, and what does display_clean() do? and where is $difference being defined in your main loop (it only exists in the function)?

Comment: Your function does not do anything, apart from creating a bunch of function local variables (won't be visible outside the function)

Comment: @MarkBaker the whole point of the code is to display it in 'posted x minutes ago', will DateTime Interval allow me to achieve this?

created_at is stored as datetime (something i can't affect), display_clean() is a custom function which does things like stripslashes() etc, and $difference doesn't appear in the actual loop. Like i said, i'm by no means competent when it comes to php, just keen to learn.

Comment: Using DateTime objects and doing a diff() will give you an Interval object, that can then be easily formatted... but looking at your code, I think you need to learn a lot more about how functions work, and variable scope, before you're ready for objects

Comment: @MarkBaker the code with the function etc isn't actually mine, i'm just trying to mash it up with my code to achieve what i want to.

Comment: @knittl i thought that's what was happening, but i wasn't sure

Comment: You need to __return__ values from your function.... simply defining a function and assuming that everything defined there will just be available everywhere in your code is wrong (and negates the whole point of even having functions)

Comment: I think maybe i should just bin this whole idea, if i'm honest

Answer (score 0):

Why not just call the original function and print out the result?

```
$sql = $db->select("SELECT * FROM `Twitter_tweets` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 0, 3");

while($res = $db->get_row($sql))
        {
            $p .= '
                <li>
                    <span class="tweetContent">'.display_clean($res['tweet']).'</span>
                    <br />
                    <span class="tweetDate">';

            $p .= ''.time_ago($res['created_at']).'</span>

                </li>
            ';
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont really understand your code, but I think there is a major syntax error in this.
If it's meant to be a function, maybe you wanted this way:

```
function time_ago($date,$granularity=2) {
    $sql = $db->select("SELECT * FROM `Twitter_tweets` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 0, 3");
    $date = strtotime($date);
    $difference = time() - $date;
    $periods = array('decade' => 315360000,
        'year' => 31536000,
        'month' => 2628000,
        'week' => 604800, 
        'day' => 86400,
        'hour' => 3600,
        'minute' => 60,
        'second' => 1); 
    while($res = $db->get_row($sql))
        {
            $p .= '
                <li>
                    <span class="tweetContent">'.display_clean($res['tweet']).'</span>
                    <br />
                    <span class="tweetDate">';

            $date = display_clean($res['created_at']);

            if ($difference < 5) { // less than 5 seconds ago, let's say "just now"
                $retval = "posted just now";
                return $retval;
            } else {                            
                foreach ($periods as $key => $value) {
                    if ($difference >= $value) {
                        $time = floor($difference/$value);
                        $difference %= $value;
                        $retval .= ($retval ? ' ' : '').$time.' ';
                        $retval .= (($time > 1) ? $key.'s' : $key);
                        $granularity--;
                    }
                if ($granularity == '0') { break; }
                }
                return ' posted '.$retval.' ago';      
            }
            $p .= '</span>

                </li>
            ';
        }
}
```

I didn't tested it, even if I wanted to I couldn't. Maybe it will help.